# Reverse ComboBox: How to programmatically select an item in ActiveX ComboBox based on a TextBox value?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have a multi-column Combobox, and tried to search for a codes for awhile now, but to no avail.

Here's my combobox looks like:

```
  emp_id         emp_name
 ---------    ---------------
  <blank>      - Select -
     1         James Bond
     2         Jason Statham
     3         Sylvester S.
     4         Chuck Norris
```

**where columnwidths = "0,100" and and columnheads = False**, so it will only show the emp_name

What I'm trying to do is, **programmatically select and display** an item from the combobox based on a variable

So far the closest logic to what I'm trying to achieve is this:

```
empSysID = 3 '~This is Sylvester S.
With .ComboBoxEmployee
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Column(0, i) = empSysID Then
            .Value = .List(i) '~Trying to select and display 'Sylvester S.' in combobox
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

But I'm getting Run-time error '380': Could not set the Value Property. Invalid property value.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `.ListIndex = i`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `ListIndex`:

```
empSysID = 3 '~This is Sylvester S.
With .ComboBoxEmployee
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Column(0, i) = empSysID Then
            .ListIndex = i 
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End With
```